# C create a txt.ppm file from a safed textfile

Tags: c, text, ppm

[PPM1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQxrS.png)

[Textfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn9UY.png)

I tried create a C code, that can create a ppm, like on the picture 1 from a textfile like on picture 3. When somemone can help, it where great. I am a new Programmer, i tried do do that Code for 6h. I tried to scan in the data from the textfile and put it in a array and try to make withe that a ppm, but my code is unusable:/.

Comment: No one can obviously help you if you do not post the code.

Comment: My code is unusable :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path forward is to split the task into smaller sub-tasks, solve and test each one of them separately, and only after they all work, combine them into a single program.

Because the OP has not posted any code, I will not post any directly useful code either. If OP is truly blocked due to not getting any forward progress even after trying, this should actually be of practical use. If OP is just looking for someone to do their homework, this should annoy them immensely. Both work for me. :)

First sub-task is to read the input in an array. There are several examples on the web, and related questions here. You'll want to put this in a separate function, so merging into the complete project later on is easier. Since you are a beginner programmer, you could go for a function like

```
int read_numbers(double data[], int max);
```

so that the caller declares the maximum number of data points, and the function returns the number of data points read; or negative if an error occurs. Your `main()` for testing that function should be trivial, say

```
#define MAX_NUMBERS 500

int main(void)
{
    double  x[MAX_NUMBERS];
    int     i, n;

    n = read_numbers(x, MAX_NUMBERS, stdin);
    if (n <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading numbers from standard input.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Read %d numbers:\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%.6f\n", x[i]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The second sub-task is to generate a PPM image. PPM is actually a group of closely related image formats, also called [Netpbm format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format)s. The example image is a bitmap image -- black and white only; no colors, no shades of gray --, so the [PBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format#PBM_example) format (or variant of PPM) is suitable for this.

I suspect it is easiest to attack this sub-task by using a two-dimensional array, sized for the largest image you can generate (i.e. `unsigned char bitmap[HEIGHT_MAX][WIDTH_MAX];`), but note that you can also just use a part of it. (You could also generate the image on the fly, without any array, but that is much more error prone, and not as universally applicable as using an array to store the image is.)

You'll probably need to decide the width of the bitmap based on the maximum data value, and the height of the bitmap based on the number of data points.

For testing, just fill the array with some simple patterns, or maybe just a diagonal line from top left corner to bottom right corner.

Then, consider writing a function that sets a rectangular area to a given value (0 or 1). Based on the image, you'll also need a function that draws vertical dotted lines, changing (exclusive-OR'ing) the state of each bit. For example,

```
#define WIDTH_MAX   1024
#define HEIGHT_MAX   768

unsigned char bitmap[HEIGHT_MAX][WIDTH_MAX];
int           width = 0;
int           height = 0;

void write_pbm(FILE *out); /* Or perhaps (const char *filename)? */

void fill_rect(int x, int y, int w, int h, unsigned char v);

void vline_xor(int x, int y, int h);
```

At this point, you should have realized that the `write_pbm()` function, the one that saves the PBM image, should be written and tested first. Then, you can use the `fill_rect()` function to not just draw filled rectangles, but also to initialize the image -- the portion of the array you are going to use -- to a background color (0 or 1). All of the three functions above you can, and should, do in separate sub-steps, so that at any point you can rely on that the code you've written earlier is correct and tested. That way, you only need to look at bugs in the code you have written since the last successful testing! It might sound like a slow way to progress, but it actually turns out to be the fastest way to get code working. You very quickly start to love the confidence the testing gives you, and the fact that you only need to focus and worry about one thing at a time.

The third sub-task is to find out a way to draw the rectangles and vertical dotted lines, for various inputs.

(I cheated a bit, above, and included the `fill_rect()` and `vline_xor()` functions in the previous sub-task, because I could tell those are needed to draw the example picture.)

The vertical dotted lines are easiest to draw afterwards, using a function that draws a vertical line, leaving every other pixel untouched, but exclusive-ors every other pixel. (Hint: `for (y = y0; y < y0 + height; y += 2) bitmap[y][x] ^= 1;`)

That leaves the filled rectangles. Their height is obviously constant, and they have a bit of vertical space in between, and they start at the left edge; so, the only thing, is to calculate how wide each rectangle needs to be. (And, how wide the entire bitmap should be, and how tall, as previously mentioned; the largest data value, and the number of data values, dictates those.)

Rather than writing one C source file, and adding to it every step, I recommend you write a separate program for each of the sub-steps. That is, after every time you get a sub-part working, you save that as a separate file, and keep it for reference -- a back-up, if you will. If you lose your way completely, or decide on another path for solving some problem, you only need to revert back to your last reference version, rather than start from scratch.

That kind of work-flow is known to be reliable, efficient, and scalable: it does not matter how large the project is, the above approach works. Of course, there are tools to help us do this in an easy, structured manner (with comments on each *commit* -- completed unit of code, if you will); and `git` is a popular, free, but very powerful one. Just do a web search for `git for beginners` if you are interested in it.

If you bothered to read all through the above wall of text, and grasped the work flow it describes, you won't have much trouble learning how to use tools like `git` to help you with the workflow. You'll also love how much typing tools like `make` (and the `Makefiles` containing the make recipes) help, and how easy it is to make and maintain projects that not only work, but also look professional. Yet, don't try to grasp all of it at once: take it one small step at a time, and verify you have a solid footing, before going onwards. That way, when you stumble, you won't hurt yourself; just learn.

Have fun!